# <br /> makes another <li>'s go out of lane

Tags: html, css

This is what happens with another `<li>` when I use `<br />` in one of them:
With `<br />`:
[image: Gives me sads]

Without `<br />`:
[image: Also gives me sads]

I don't really know if I should use ul,li here. It would be nice if you told me.
My code:
html

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<a href="#link"><li><p>Text</p></li></a>
<a href="#link"><li><p>Text</p></li></a>
<a href="#link"><li><p>Text</p></li></a>
<a href="#link"><li><p>Text</p></li></a>
<a href="#link"><li><p>Text in two lines</p></li></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.menu{
    height: 96px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 96px;
    width: 96px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-image: url("../images/menu-button.png");
}

.menu li:hover{
    background-image: url("../images/menu-button-hover.png");
}

.menu p{
    top:40px;
    position:relative;
}

.menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.menu a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Thanks in advance, waiting for a help!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot put other elements in a list outside of an LI. They must all be INSIDE the LI. What you're doing will never work.

Comment: use `word-wrap: break-word;` css.

Comment: I put everything in a LI but still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Still same problem when I use `<br />`. Another buttons gets pushed
>   down.

Where you have `display: inline-block`, you also need `vertical-align: top`.

(The default is `vertical-align: baseline`.)

Answer (score 1):

Just as Diodeus said, your markup is invalid. It should look something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#link">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link">Text in two lines</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

While you *can* have a paragraph tag in there, since you only have just a small amount of text, it's really kid of overkill (unless you need the extra hook for styling or something).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/fZ4Ld/)

Comment: Still same problem when I use <br />. Another buttons gets pushed down.

Comment: I added a link to a JSFiddle that I think will solve your issue.